# ocaml formatters and value restriction

Tags: ocaml, string-formatting, value-restriction

**EDIT**: *I'm sorry everyone, I thought my small examle was complete, turns out it's not.*
I made a new one that really should be!

As soon as I use a formatter as parameter to Scanf or Printf functions the formatter type gets bound to a in- or output-channel respectively.
Is there a way to have a function take a formatter (or string) and use that as a formatter for both printing and reading?

```
let fmt = format_of_string "%d,%d";;
Scanf.sscanf "2,2" fmt (fun x y -> x,y);;
fmt;;
```

gives

```
- : (int -> int -> int * int, Scanf.Scanning.scanbuf, '_a, (int -> int -> int * int) -> int * int, (int -> int -> int * int) -> int * int, int * int) format6 = <abstr>
```

Which means a subsequent `Printf.printf fmt 1 2;;` gives a type error.
This goes for every combination of `format_of_string` and `Scanf.format_from_string` like functions I've tried.

Example:

```
module Thing = struct

(* Just a helper for file IO *)
type 'a result = Success of 'a | Failure of exn;;
let with_out_file filename fn =
  let out_ch = open_out filename in
  let res = try Success (fn out_ch) with
    exn -> Failure exn in
  close_out out_ch;
match res with
| Success a -> a
| Failure a -> raise a;;

(* Uses the format string for writing *)
let print (fmt : ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6) fn v =
  with_out_file fn (fun x -> Printf.fprintf x fmt v);;

(* Uses the format string for reading *)
let read (fmt : ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6) v =
  Scanf.sscanf v fmt (fun x -> x);;

(* Where things break *)
let both fmt v =
  read fmt "42\n";
  print fmt "tfile" v;;
end;;
```

Gives

```
Error: This expression has type ('a -> 'b, Scanf.Scanning.scanbuf, 'c, ('d -> 'd) -> 'e, ('a -> 'b) -> 'f, 'f) format6 but an expression was expected of type                                                       
     ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit) format6                                                                                                                                                    
   Type Scanf.Scanning.scanbuf is not compatible with type out_channel
```

For the last line of the `both` function, which seems to make sense,
but if I remove the `both` function from the module, I can call `read` and `print` with the same format string (same variable as parameter) and it just works.

So, with hopes that you guys haven't given up on me yet; how do I get around that?
neither eta-expansion nor type annotation seems to work in this case?

Comment: An example would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Realized it the moment I had posted :)

Answer (score 5):

You're hitting the infamous [value restriction](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html#the-value-restriction):

```
# let fmt = format_of_string "%d,%d";;
val fmt : (int -> int -> '_a, '_b, '_c, '_d, '_d, '_a) format6 = <abstr>
```

Those `'_a`, `'_b`, `'_c`, `'_d` mean "types to be determined as soon as we can". They are *not* parameters, i.e., `fmt` is not a polymorphic value. In contrast, an empty list is polymorphic:

```
# let emptiness = [] ;;
val emptiness : 'a list = []
```

Now we have `'a` and *not* `'_a`. But maybe you already know all this. The point is that when we apply `Printf.printf` to `fmt`, its type gets fixed as

```
(int -> int -> unit, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit) format6
```

but when we apply `Scanf.sscanf` to `fmt` its type gets fixed as

```
(int -> int -> int * int, Scanf.Scanning.in_channel, '_a,
(int -> int -> int * int) -> int * int,
(int -> int -> int * int) -> int * int, int * int)
format6
```

These two types are not compatible, and because `fmt` is not polymorphic, you cannot use it both ways. The solution is simply to have two copies, `fmt_in` and `fmt_out`. Is there something unacceptable with that solution?

Comment: 'Is there something unacceptable with that solution' -- Sort of.
I'm making a module/library, and would like to avoid the uncleanliness of taking the same parameter twice, but also; I've been unable to pull it off. Saving two identical formatters binds them to the same restricted types. Using one binds the type of both.

Comment: Explanation: I upvoted your answer (because It is a great answer), but accepted Jeffreys because the question actually states that the problem is with value restriction, and asks for a work-around.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea is to make `fmt` a function rather than an actual format value:

```
# let fmt () = format_of_string "%d,%d";;
val fmt : unit -> (int -> int -> 'a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'd, 'a) format6 = <fun>
# Scanf.sscanf "2,2" (fmt ()) (fun x y -> (x, y));;
- : int * int = (2, 2)
# Printf.printf (fmt ()) 3 4;;
3,4- : unit = ()
```

This is a little clunky, but maybe not too bad...?

Comment: A little clunky, yes, but it works, which is more than anything I've tried. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Your example does not obey the value restriction since it is a function application. However, the call to `format_of_string` is not necessary. `format_of_string` is actually just the identity function with type

```
('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6 -> ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6
```

It works by forcing a type annotation on its argument, which causes the literal to be interpreted as a format specifier instead of a string.

Instead you can simply provide the type annotation directly yourself:

```
# let fmt : ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f) format6 = "%d,%d";;
val fmt : (int -> int -> 'f, 'b, 'c, 'e, 'e, 'f) format6 = <abstr>
```

Note that the type is now fully polymorphic because the expression is now a value.

*Update:* In OCaml 4.02 you can now shorten the type annotation to:

```
let fmt : _ format6 = "%d,%d";;
```

Comment: Wonderful!
While long type annotations are not exactly pretty, it's far less hacky than wrapping a value in a function.

Could you explain _why_ my example is a function application though? Why isn't format_of_string "%d,%d" evaluated to a value?

Comment: The value restriction is a *syntactic* restriction. `format_of_string "%d%d"` is syntactically a function application, since function applications can have side-effects it is not considered a value.

Comment: But the result stored as fmt, that isn't considered a value either?
I would get it if it was a partial application, but it's not.

Comment: The result is not important, what matters is whether there may have been side effects whilst creating the result. I suggest you read up on the [value restriction](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html#the-value-restriction).

Comment: Makes sense, I'm still having some problems with it though.